# Can't seem to figure out the segmentation fault in this

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out why gbd is showing a seg fault in this.

My `main` is calling a function `int* max_min(s, &size, &max, &min);`

And in `max_min(char* filename, unsigned long long int* size, int* max, int* min);`
I calculate the `file_size` using `file_stat` and store it in `size`. I then proceed to read a file using a file pointer `fp` which I declared. I return a `buffer` of type `int*` from this function.

According to `gdb` by seg fault is at these statements:

`int* buffer = max_min(s, &size, &max, &min);` in `int main()` 
&

`unsigned long long int amount = fread(buffer, sizeof(int), *size, fp);` in my `max_min` function.

```
int main()
{
    char* s = argv[2]; //Gets the filename.
    unsigned long long int size;
    int min, max;
    int* buffer = max_min(s, &size, &max, &min);
    return 0;
}

int* max_min(char* filename, unsigned long long int* size, int *max, int *min)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    struct stat file_stat;
    unsigned long long int amount;
    stat(filename, &file_stat);
    *size = file_stat.st_size;
    *size /= sizeof(int);
    int* buffer = malloc(*size *sizeof(int));
    amount = fread(buffer, sizeof(int), *size, fp);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: What is `argv[2]`?

Comment: So you opened a file, didn't check if `fopen` as successful, and then read from the file and get a segfault?  Try checking that `fp` is not NULL.

Comment: And Check return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Every time you have code that fails when opening a file without checking for success, the first thing to do is add a check on opening the file. Lesson: _always_ check whether files open successfully, even in pretend code.

Comment: And of `stat()`.  And of `fread()`, though the failure occurs before you could do the last.

Comment: You don't even check if `argv[2]` exists! Check *everything* or your program will be impossible to debug.